# How can I hide passwords or use secrets in Testcafe?

Tags: security, testing, automated-tests, passwords, testcafe

I am currently testing a login page and therefore I need to hide the password in the code because in our company it's prohibited to check-in passwords in Git.

Is there any known pattern how I can hide passwords or use secrets in Testcafe?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass sensitive data through environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cryptr library, more details here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptr
And the key used can be pushed into environment/database.